# Did the prophets deal with another divine being?

Tags: torah-study, tanach

Hosea 1:7

> וְאֶת־בֵּ֤ית יְהוּדָה֙ אֲרַחֵ֔ם וְהֽוֹשַׁעְתִּ֖ים בַּיהוָ֣ה אֱלֹֽהֵיהֶ֑ם וְלֹ֣א אֽוֹשִׁיעֵ֗ם בְּקֶ֤שֶׁת וּבְחֶ֙רֶב֙ וּבְמִלְחָמָ֔ה בְּסוּסִ֖ים וּבְפָרָשִֽׁים׃

> But I will accept the House of Judah. And I will give them victory **through the LORD their God**; I will not give them victory with bow and sword and battle, by horses and riders.”

Genesis 19:24

> וַֽיהוָ֗ה הִמְטִ֧יר עַל־סְדֹ֛ם וְעַל־עֲמֹרָ֖ה גָּפְרִ֣ית וָאֵ֑שׁ מֵאֵ֥ת יְהוָ֖ה מִן־הַשָּׁמָֽיִם׃

> **the LORD rained** upon Sodom and Gomorrah sulfurous fire from **the LORD out of heaven**.

Genesis 35:1

> וַיֹּ֤אמֶר אֱלֹהִים֙ אֶֽל־יַעֲקֹ֔ב ק֛וּם עֲלֵ֥ה בֵֽית־אֵ֖ל וְשֶׁב־שָׁ֑ם וַעֲשֵׂה־שָׁ֣ם מִזְבֵּ֔חַ לָאֵל֙ הַנִּרְאֶ֣ה אֵלֶ֔יךָ בְּבָרְחֲךָ֔ מִפְּנֵ֖י עֵשָׂ֥ו אָחִֽיךָ׃

> **God said** to Jacob, “Arise, go up to Bethel and remain there; and build an altar there to **the God who appeared to you** when you were fleeing from your brother Esau.”

Christians use these verses to proof that Tanach recognizes another divine distinct being "they claim it is Jesus".
I'm confused, how to understand those verses?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.19.24.4?lang=bi

Comment: I don't get the question. How can G-d refer to Himself in third person?

Comment: @JoelK so helpful !! thanks sir

Comment: @robev how can to refer to himself in third person as it there an another mentioned divine being

Comment: How can robev refer to himself in third person? Why not..

Comment: @JoelK also in ibn Ezra to Gen 2.20 in [these](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?book=1&perek=2&mefaresh=ezra) [versions](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%91#%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A7_%D7%9B_(%D7%9B%D7%9C_%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7)(%D7%9B%D7%9C_%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A7)) (sorry, I don't see it English)

Comment: @davidcowboy They confuse the difference between G-d and His names. G-d has many names. But there is only one G-d, and G-d is one like we learn from Moshe Rabbeinu in connection with the Shema.